# Eliminate results based on value

Tags: sql

```
SALESID         PURCHID         ACKNUMBER   CONFIRMEDDLV
SO-0446950      PO-057272       109754      2014-04-21 00:00:00.000
SO-0446950      PO-057272       109754      2014-04-21 00:00:00.000
SO-0446950      PO-057273       109754      2014-01-10 00:00:00.000
SO-0446950      PO-057272                   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
SO-0449613      PO-061115                   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
SO-0449613      PO-061115                   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
SO-0461621      PO-058821       5375543     2014-01-30 00:00:00.000
SO-0461621      PO-058821       5375543     2014-01-30 00:00:00.000
```

I want to eliminate a salesid if one of the rows for the sales id does not have a value in acknumber. The correct results from above would be SO-0461621 only.

```
SELECT sal.SALESID , 
       lne.PURCHID , 
       lne.ACKNUMBER , 
       lne.CONFIRMEDDLV
  FROM
       SALESTABLE Sal LEFT JOIN SALESLINE SalLne ON Sal.SALESID = SalLne.SALESID
                      LEFT JOIN PURCHLINE Lne ON Lne.INVENTTRANSID = SalLne.INVENTREFTRANSID
  WHERE SalLne.INVENTREFID LIKE 'PO%'
    AND sal.SALESSTATUS IN( 0 , 1 )
    AND sal.SALESPOOLID <> 'FURN-CONF'
    AND sal.DLVMODE LIKE 'FURN%';
```

Comment: Add `and ACKNUMBER is not null`?

Comment: and acknumber is not null / <> '' would remove the row but not the entire salesid set

Comment: so do a subquery instead.  Something like where id is NOT in (select id from table where acknumber is null)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sal.SALESID , 
       lne.PURCHID , 
       lne.ACKNUMBER , 
       lne.CONFIRMEDDLV
  FROM
       SALESTABLE Sal LEFT JOIN SALESLINE SalLne ON Sal.SALESID = SalLne.SALESID
                      LEFT JOIN PURCHLINE Lne ON Lne.INVENTTRANSID = SalLne.INVENTREFTRANSID
  WHERE SalLne.INVENTREFID LIKE 'PO%'
    AND sal.SALESSTATUS IN( 0 , 1 )
    AND sal.SALESPOOLID <> 'FURN-CONF'
    AND sal.DLVMODE LIKE 'FURN%'
    and not sal.SALESID in (select SALESID from SALESTABLE where ACKNUMBER   is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a sub-query, you can just add another condition to your WHERE clause

```
SELECT sal.SALESID , 
   lne.PURCHID , 
   lne.ACKNUMBER , 
   lne.CONFIRMEDDLV
FROM
   SALESTABLE Sal LEFT JOIN SALESLINE SalLne ON Sal.SALESID = SalLne.SALESID
                  LEFT JOIN PURCHLINE Lne ON Lne.INVENTTRANSID = SalLne.INVENTREFTRANSID
WHERE SalLne.INVENTREFID LIKE 'PO%'
  AND sal.SALESSTATUS IN( 0 , 1 )
  AND sal.SALESPOOLID <> 'FURN-CONF'
  AND sal.DLVMODE LIKE 'FURN%';
  AND Lne.ACKNUMBER IS NOT NULL
```

Also you say in your post that the only data that SHOULD be returned is "SO-0461621" however it looks like "SO-0446950" has a valid value in ACKNUMBER as well...should both of those SALESID's be returned?  Hope this helps!